# different external ip addresses ? (trying to ftp connect remotely with router)

Tags: ftp, ip, router

When I'm behind a router, my external ip is different. Why ?

With router : 24.121.18.38

Without router : 24.55.18.133

Why?

Without router, I can ftp connect remotely to my computer with 24.55.18.133
With router, I cannot ftp connect remotely to my computer with 24.121.18.38.

Why? And how can I connect remotly while using a router ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect remotely to your computer when a router is between because the router blocks traffic when port forwarding is not active.

You could make conencting possible by activating port forwarding. Which ports you will have to forward depends on ftp mode and your settings.

Your external IP's could differ because they are either assigned to Mac-Addresses by the router above or because of DHCP of your ISP which assigns IP Adresses to devices until they are released.